# Suggested Indexing for table with 50 million rows is queried using its CREATED_DATE column and USER_TYPE column

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Table **Users**:

```
ID  PK INT
USER_TYPE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
CREATED_DATE DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
```

I have this table with 50 million rows, and it is queries using the following where clause:

```
WHERE
    u.USER_TYPE= 'manager' 
    AND u.CREATED_DATE >= @StartDate
    AND u.CREATED_DATE < @EndDate
```

What would be a good starting point for an index on this table to optimize for the above query where clause?

Answer (score 2):

For that query, the index you want is a composite index with two columns:  `(user_type, created_date)`.  The order matters, you want `user_type` first because of the equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be well served by creating a table with user types having an arbitrary INT ID and referring to the manager type by ID, instead of having the manager type directly in the users table. This will narrow the table data as well as any index referring to the user type.

```
CREATE TABLE user_type (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    description NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_user_type PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(id)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    user_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_user_type FOREIGN KEY(user_type_id) REFERENCES user_type(id)
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
    ix_users_type_created
ON
    users (
        user_type_id,
        created_date
    );
```

You would be querying using the `user_type` ID rather than directly with the text of course.

Answer (score 0):

For any query. Run the query in SSMS with "Include Actual Execution Plan" on. SSMS will advice an index if it feels proper index doesn't exist.